# Numbers in the title page do not appear in dvi file

Tags: pdftex, dvi

The authors name appears as follows in pdf output:

```
Ali Balador1;2, Carlos T. Calafate1, and Juan-Carlos Cano1
1Universitat Politecnica de Valencia, Spain, alba6@upv.es, {calafate, jucano}@disca.upv.es
2Halmstad University, Sweden
```

but in the dvi file numbers do not appear. what is the solution?

the code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\newcommand\Mark[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{authblk}
\let\labelindent\relax
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\title{title}
\author[Ali Balador et al.]
       {Ali Balador$^{1,2}$, Carlos T. Calafate$^1$, and Juan-Carlos Cano$^1$\\
       $^1$Universitat Politecnica de Valencia, Spain,
       alba6@upv.es, \{calafate, jucano\}@disca.upv.es\\
       $^2$Halmstad University, Sweden\\
   }
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you post a mwe?

Comment: @touhami you mean the code?

Comment: yes a minimale but complete code

Comment: @touhami I uploaded the min code.

Comment: there is no problem when i try it in a basic file with article.cls. that's why we need a complete code: `\documentclass...\end{document}` but minimale just the necessary

Comment: @touhami could you check again the code. Is it enough? I need to mention that the pdf output is ok but when I compile with latex option no.

Comment: your code works fine for me, so sorry i can't help you